# Prove the Descartes' rule of signs

Tags: polynomials, roots, multinomial-coefficients

$N$ is the number of positive roots of $$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$

$M$ is the number sign change in the sequence of non-zero coefficients. Prove that $M \geq N$ and $2 \mid (M-N)$.

It's quite common but I still can't have any idea. Please help me :((

Comment: C'mon, Descartes proved this centuries ago, so you should be able to do it too!

Comment: @CountIblis, I think time has nothing to do with one's ability to proof a theorem or a rule. I don't think the proof is trivial. A so called "simple proof" may be found here:https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xiaoshen_Wang/publication/245067545_A_Simple_Proof_of_Descartes's_Rule_of_Signs/links/56df040d08ae979addef4d34.pdf